# Add new macros to already created installer Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an installer named as Vita-E.exe.
[image]
This is an installer for installing addins in excel.
[image]

After installing the vitaE, it gets added in the excel(obviously).Now I have been given chance to create new macros and add the macros in the previously created installer.There are pre-added macros, the ones I created are AddApostroph, CleanRemoveNonPrintable, ClearPrintArea, ConvertPercentageToNumber, CopyValuesToEmptyCells.
[image]

I don't know how to add the new macros in the ribbon. I added the the new created macros as modules in the addin. But I am not able to see them in the ribbon. The vitaE has around 20 macros, and I have created around 15 new ones. I want to add them in the ribbon by using the installer. How can I do it? I'm not finding solution for this.

Comment: You'll need to modify the `VitaE1.xlam` in your installer with your new ribbon. Have a look at this for info about customising ribbons [link](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)

Comment: Okay. So this will change the ribbon. But will the installer be changed too ? I mean currently, on installing the addin, it adds around 20. After I add more 15 in the customUI in the xml code, will the installer show those 15 newly added as well ? (after changing the ribbon)

Comment: No - you'll need to modify the installer for however it creates the add-in. My guess would be it copies the `xlam` file into place. If you're able to modify the file inside the installer with your ribbon changes then that would solve your issue. To do that though you'll probably need the source code.